# How to show the whole chip text in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I'm trying to display the whole text in my flutter chip but some reason it got faded if the text is longer than the chip so I would be really appreciated if I can get any help on how I can display the whole full text without it being faded?.

```
  Widget _widgetToAdd(String i) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
      height: height * 0.05,
      width: 100,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
      child: Chip(
        label: Text(
          i,
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
      ),
    );
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < listOfTages.length; i++) {
    list.add(_widgetToAdd(listOfTages[i]));
  }

  return Wrap(children: list);
}
```

[image]

Comment: @dm_tr I'm using material.dart

Answer (score 1):

Either remove or increase the `width` property of the parent `Container`

```
Container(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
  height: height * 0.05,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
  child: Chip(
    label: Text(i, style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black,
      fontSize: 16,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    ),),
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The label of the chip have as a default value of TextOverflow.fade

You can overwrite this value like this:

```
Widget _widgetToAdd(String i) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
      height: height * 0.05,
      width: 100,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
      child: Chip(
        label: Text(
          i,
          overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
      ),
    );
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < listOfTages.length; i++) {
    list.add(_widgetToAdd(listOfTages[i]));
  }

  return Wrap(children: list);
}
```